# Formula in linear models

Tags: r

Sometimes I use `$` in formula of linear models, which kind of works but gives strange answers.  Consider the following

```
library (ISLR)

agelims<-range(Wage$age)
age.grid<-seq(from=agelims[1],to=agelims[2])

fitX<-lm(wage~poly(age,4),data=Wage)
predsX<-predict(fitX,newdata=list(age=age.grid),se=TRUE)

fit<-lm(Wage$wage~poly(Wage$age,4),data=Wage)
preds<-predict(fit,newdata=list(age=age.grid),se=TRUE)
```

so in fit I refer to wage as `Wage$wage` which seems correct but superfluous.  R obviously disagrees because if you run `preds$fit` and `predsX$fit` one gives you thousands of predictions and the other gives you only 63.

What the heck is happening here?

Comment: Just don't use `$` in the formula. Problem solved?

Comment: True - but I am trying to deepen my knowledge of R - why is it doing this?

Comment: If you use `$` in the formula, `predict` doesn't work and returns the fitted values instead of the predictions for the new data.

Comment: Okay - but if predict doesn't work why doesn't it just return a syntax error?

Comment: Because it is actually no so simple to define what should considered an error here. `help("predict.lm")` says "Variables are first looked for in newdata and then searched for in the usual way (which will include the environment of the formula used in the fit)."  The variable name searched for isactually `Wage$age` and obviously such a variable is not in `new.data`. So everything works as documented and you should never use `$` in the formula is you want to predict. It's superfluous anyway if you specify `data`.

Comment: Okay - thanks for the response.  How do I award you the answer?

Comment: @[Dano13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9914058/dano13) you cannot, from here. @[Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) has to post it in answer section & then you could accept it. Not possible in comments section!